# How to perform this restriction in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I created this table:

```
create table sales(
    code              varchar(3)
    saledate          date,
    CONSTRAINT pk_codesale PRIMARY KEY (code)
);
```

the date will be the fifth day of each month, but if it's Monday , the date will be the next day , ie , the sixth day .

Comment: What is your question?  I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I try to do the restriction but nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a CHECK-constraint:

```
check((extract(day from saledate) = 5 and -- 5. day of month
       extract(dow from saledate) <> 1)   -- but no monday
      or
      (extract(day from saledate) = 6 and -- 6. day of month
       extract(dow from saledate) = 2)    -- and tuesday
     )
```

Edit:

If you want to modify any date during the Insert/Update to the 5. or 6. of that month you should do that in your application. In SQL it's a bit complicated, a trigger might be the way to go. I don't have expertise in writing triggers in PG, but the modifying logic is like this:

```
date_trunc('mon',:inDate) + interval '4' day
+ (case
     when extract(dow from date_trunc('mon',:inDate) + interval '4' day) = 1 
     then 1 
     else 0 
     end * interval '1' day)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply , but there is some way that all this is done by default?

Comment: @postgresqlx12: What do you mean *by default*? When you add this check to the CREATE TABLE PostgreSQL will return an error message whenever you try to insert "wrong" values.

Comment: The check constraint *prevents* the wrong data from being entered.  But it does not *change* the data to be the correct date.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Now I got it, the OP talked about *restriction*.